# Does current 64-bit Unity 2020 still support 32-bit (x86) native DLLs?

Tags: unity-game-engine, x86, interop

Does current 64-bit Unity still support 32-bit (x86) native DLLs?

I have a large x86 DLL with a nice C API, and an Interop file in C# that works perfectly, except in Unity. I've set all the options I can find to x86, and I've tried putting it in Plugins/x86.

Either it just doesn't find the DLL, or it finds it and complains that I need to convert it to 64-bit. But I can't do that.

Either (a) somewhere is a key factor I'm missing or (b) it can't be done and my project is dead. Which is it? A bit of sample code or a tutorial would help. I'm out of ideas.

---

The key to my question is that this is only about Unity, not about the general issue of x64 vs x86. The other questions are irrelevant.

And the answer is: No, you cannot use a 32-bit DLL in the Unity Editor but Yes, you can use 32-bit DLLs in a build of Unity with an x86 target. Unity allows you to provide multiple DLLs to target different platforms, but for the Editor it has to be 64-bit.

I think that's a reasonable question and a useful answer, which I have not seen stated elsewhere. I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: These other answers are irrelevant because they don't mention Unity.

Comment: Does "64-bit Unity" not imply a 64-bit DLL, and thus a 64-bit process?  Either way, the duplicates make it clear that only a 32-bit process can directly use a 32-bit DLL, from which everything else follows, including that you need a 32-bit build of the Unity library to use it in the same process as another 32-bit DLL.

Comment: I guess fair enough to state the available bitnesses of the DLLs vs. editor, that's the other necessary fact that constrains one's options.  Isn't it open-source, though? So one might expect that you could make a 32-bit build of the editor.

Answer (score 1):

A 64bit executable cannot call a 32bit dll and viceversa. So you cannot use 32-bit plugins for the unity editor because the editor is only available as a 64-bit platform.

Comment: This answer might be helpful, because it suggests the problem is specific to the 64-bit Unity Editor, and not to the Unity platform itself. Was this the intention?